# Javascript regex to validate GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form where a user inserts the GPS coordinates of a location to a corresponding photo.  Its easy enough to filter out invalid numbers, since I just have to test for a range of (-90, 90), (-180, 180) for lat/long coordinates.

However, this also means that regular text is valid input.

I've tried changing the test pattern to

```
var pattern= "^[a-zA-Z]"
```

and is used in the function to detect alphabetical characters

```
$(".lat").keyup(function(){
  var thisID= this.id;
  var num = thisID.substring(3, thisID.length);
  var thisVal = $(this).val();

  //if invalid input, show error message and hide save button
  if (pattern.test(thisVal)){
    $("#latError"+num).fadeIn(250);
    $("#save"+num).fadeOut(100)
  } 
  else { //otherwise, hide error message and show save
    $("#save"+num).fadeIn(250);
    $("#latError"+num).fadeOut(100);
  }
});
```

However, this doesn't work as Firebug complains that `pattern.test` is not a function  What would solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide example input and output?

Comment: "[^a-zA-Z]" <- how about that?

Comment: @LarryBattle, valid sample values for the latitude would be `43.06982`, -80.3847`.  Invalid values would be greater than 90 and less than -90

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky, still broken.  I get `pattern.test` is not a function

Comment: the right answer is below where this is: var pattern = /[^a-zA-Z]/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the pattern `-?[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]+` then you [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) and check the range as you said before.

Comment: Doesn't this permit any character in the place where the period should be?

Comment: `/^-?[\d]{1,3}[.][\d]+$/`, assuming you're checking the lat/lng separately

Answer (score 25):

This is what i use in my project:

```
const regexLat = /^(-?[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d{1,18})?|90(?:\.0{1,18})?)$/;
const regexLon = /^(-?(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])?\d(?:\.\d{1,18})?|180(?:\.0{1,18})?)$/;

function check_lat_lon(lat, lon) {
  let validLat = regexLat.test(lat);
  let validLon = regexLon.test(lon);
  return validLat && validLon;
}
```

check_lat_lon(-34.11242, -58.11547) Will return TRUE if valid, else FALSE

I hope this will be usefull to you!

Comment: The best solution; also checks for -90-90, -180-180 ranges. Should be considered as better answer, for sure.

Comment: i know im a little late to the party, but for cleanliness, lets make it `return (validLat && validLong)`

Answer (score 18):

Do you need to use regex? Consider the following:

```
var val = parseFloat(lat);
if (!isNaN(val) && val <= 90 && val >= -90)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: Notice that comparing with `NaN` will always return `true` in your case. Use `!isNaN(val)` instead.

Comment: @Cyrbil. Nice spot. Equality with NaN is always false. `NaN == NaN -> false`.

Comment: Yeah I just came accross this javascript nonsense, with another though you can also remove the `isNaN` and compare simply on the range.

Answer (score 3):

`test()` is a method of the `RegExp` object - you're running it on a string, so will fail.

Enclose your pattern in a RegExp literal (`/pattern/`), so

```
var pattern= /^[a-zA-Z]/
```

That will get rid of the errors you're getting, but you have a separate issue with regards to a) whether your pattern is correct for what you want it to do; b) whether you need REGEX at all.

REGEX acts on strings - it cannot be used to determine whether a number is within a given range (unless that range is 0-10 inclusive).

@flem's answer shows the best way to approach what you're doing - no REGEX needed. The call to `parseInt()` will catch non-numeric characters since it will return `NaN` if the value contains any.

Answer (score 0):

@paul flemming gave a great answer, this answer extends his and includes longitude and uses typescript.
I would suggest this in place of regex for speed and simplicity.

Since, parseFloat takes a string and returns a number isNaN check isn't needed. This function allows a string or a number and converts it to string for parseFloat and will then do the simple threshold tests against  +-90 & +-180.

```
function isValidLatAndLong(lat: number |string, lon:number|string){
    const num1 = "" +lat; //convert toString
    const num2 = "" +lon;
    if (parseFloat(num1) <= 90 && parseFloat(num1) >= -90 && parseFloat(num2) <= 180 && parseFloat(num2) >= -180){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
  }
```